# Get active local notification alert type or local notification alertview button click event in ios

Tags: ios, notifications, uilocalnotification, localnotification

I am trying to get active local notification alert style for app in settings.

I got following code to get it but it's not working for local notification.

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

I just need to know which kind of alert type is set by user in settings i.e. None, Banners, Alerts...

Or

I am getting alert for local notification when alert style is set to **Alerts** in Settings for app. But I am not getting click event for this any of those button.

I need to take decision based upon click event of button or Active local notification alert style. If I can get click event of that button or active notification alert style for app then it would be very helpful for me.

Thanks for your help in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
UIRemoteNotificationType types = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] enabledRemoteNotificationTypes];
```

Now you can just check

```
if (types & UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)
```

Will return YES if `"Alert Style"` is set to `"Banners" or "Alerts"`,

and NO if `"Alert Style"` is set to `"None"`.

Comment: you want to change notification type using API ?

Comment: No, I just want to know active notification type from settings for app.

Comment: Refer it if you miss any thing :
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/enabledRemoteNotificationTypes